# Is there a descriptor for courses/classes you take without necessarily being in college?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if you take a class on sewing or boating, basically any class you might take for your personal development or wanting to learn a new skill. It might be offered by a school, or maybe by a local community organization. Could there be a word to describe that type of independent class? I feel like saying "classes" automatically makes people think of school. So, just like the way we say "college classes", might there be a "_____ classes" for this other scenario?

Comment: If you are taking classes at a college but not for college credit then that is called *Auditing* the class. You can do this whether you are going to the college or not. Is your question about courses *not* at college?

Comment: In the UK, such courses are described as _Adult Education_.

Comment: The best answers are already given above and below, but other terms (at least in the UK) are *continuing education*, *lifelong learning*, and *evening classes* (the last is sometimes used loosely to denote courses at other times of day).

Answer (score 1):

In many circumstances, when the classes are organised by an institute of education such as a university, college or school, classes not held in the institution, or held for students who are not part of the institution’s registered student body, are *extramural*.

> = organized by a college or university, etc. for people who are not students there:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extramural)

From the Latin: extra + murus; “outside the walls”.